# Dashed SVG line with non-dashed marker in Safari

Tags: svg, safari, cross-browser, webkit

I want a dashed line with a non-dashed arrow head, but in Safari the dashiness is apparently also applied on the markers.

Demo:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">

  <defs>

    <marker style="overflow:visible" id="myMarker" refX="0.0" refY="0.0" orient="auto">
      <path transform="scale(-0.4) translate(-3,0)" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 5.77,0.0 L -2.88,5.0 L -2.88,-5.0 L 5.77,0.0 z "></path>
    </marker>

  </defs>

  <line class="line" stroke-dasharray="5,5" x1="20" y1="20" x2="80" y2="80" marker-start="url(#myMarker)" stroke-width="10" stroke="black"></line>

</svg>
```

How it looks like in Firefox (and Chrome), that's how I want it to be:
[image: Firefox]

How it looks like in Safari (12.0 and the current Technology Preview):
[image: Safari]

Setting `stroke-dasharray` to `0` or an empty string for the `<path>` of the marker does not seem to have any effect at all. Setting it to `1 0` (which smells like a hack) does nearly perfect, but the arrow head's tip is not pointy:

[image: Safari non-pointy tip]

How to best override this behaviour of Safari and get a dashed line with non-dashed arrow head with a pointy tip? Is there something I am missing why Safari is behaving this way or is this simply a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've rewritten the path for the marker. Now it begins in the middle of the side instead of the vertex. Also I'm using `stroke-dasharray="30,0"`where 30 is the length of the path for the marker.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">

  <defs>

    <marker style="overflow:visible" id="myMarker" refX="0.0" refY="0.0" orient="auto">
      <path transform="scale(-0.4) translate(-3,0)" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1" d="M-2.88,0L-2.88,5L 5.77,0L -2.88,-5L-2.88,0z" stroke-dasharray="30,0"></path>
    </marker>

  </defs>

  <line class="line" stroke-dasharray="5,5" x1="20" y1="20" x2="80" y2="80" marker-start="url(#myMarker)" stroke-width="10" stroke="black"></line>
  


</svg>
```